# Front panel audio jacks and rear microphone jack non-functional

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, microphone, 21.10

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 21.10, my front panel headphone and microphone jacks are non-functional. When I plug in my headset into each port, Ubuntu recognizes this and displays "Headphones - USB Audio" and "Microphone - USB Audio" under the output and input sections. However, no sound is played, and the microphone does not pick up anything. My front panel ports work since I tested them with another operating system. Using my motherboard's line in and out ports, I can get sound to work, and Ubuntu displays "Speakers - USB Audio" and "Line-In - USB Audio," but my microphone records sound coming from Ubuntu (ex: If I'm watching YouTube, the sound meter will peak along with the sound from the video). I've tried using a live Ubuntu USB of 21.10 and 20.04.3, but I have the same exact issues. I also reinstalled 21.10, but I have had no luck. Using `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` in terminal returns this:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-H HD Audio Controller (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Tiger Lake-H HD Audio Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at a3510000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a3100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

--
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP104 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at a3080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V (rev 03)
```

Motherboard: MSI MPG Z590 Gaming Plus
Processor: Intel Core i7 11700k
Case: Corsair Crystal Series 460X RGB
Thank you!

Comment: I got motherboard Asus z690-p and I don't even have onboard audio in alsa, meaning it doesn't work either